# Custom theme for ReactJS Project

Tags: css, reactjs, themes

I'm working in a personal project with React created by create-react-app. With this I have a style guide with the font-family, primary colors, styled buttons, icons and other custom components like check-box, input forms, etc.

What I want to know is which is the best way to work with this customize elements with React?

Do I need to create a CSS class with all of my configurations and added in every component that I'm using?

Or, Do I need to create something like a custom theme for using it with react?

The goal that I want to reach is using this customize styles for my project like I'm using bootstrap or other CSS framework.

Comment: regarding styling with `React` a good option is [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) .. and for global app theme a nice package is [styled-components](https://dev.to/aromanarguello/how-to-use-themes-in-styled-components-49h)

Comment: thanks @OmarDieh I'll check those links!

Answer (score 1):

Mui lets you customize the themes very easily if you choose to go with it!
You can even use the theme generator https://bareynol.github.io/mui-theme-creator/

It's also nice if you choose to include dark/light mode later on like this
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/#toggling-color-mode